# lookup column added calculated column formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I created a list of date where my team members can meet. It is a lookup column.

Now I have to write a formula with this lookup column in a new column called formula1. For example "`=NOT([Due Date]=0)`". Meaning that if the column "Due Date" is empty, I will have a "No" in the column formula1.

After some research on the internet, a found that it wasn't possible to create a calculated column based on a lookup column.

Have you any idea how to skirt this limitation ?

Comment: Not, only simple column types can be used

Comment: Lookup columns cannot be used in Calculated formula

Answer (score 2):

Yes you cannot apply formula on look-up columns. But one workaround i could suggest is to use Javascript. Since the list is showed in a table form, you could change the text of every td of this specific tr to 'No' where ever there is an empty string. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. What is td and tr ?
I have the date in a table form based on a list.

Comment: See the list view web part is viewed in a tabular form, so it will obviously have tr(table rows) and td ( table data). Check on Google, HTML tables. You can use JavaScript to pick these td/tr accordingly. Google a little and you will get Javascript functions too. Let me know if you need more help.